# how to style a nav bar, logo and title in angular bootstrap 4 web app?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

Im trying to make the top of the webpage so its a grid of ratio 3:6 with the section on the left being a square image. and the section on the right being split horizontally in 2 with the top half being a bar with the title and the bottom half a naviagtion bar. this is my code. unfortuanetly the title is not appearing at all, and the image is appearing on top of the navigation bar and also not filling the width of the screen. Im really not sure what the problem. any help would be great! thanks

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
   <img ng-src="img/sky-logo.jpg" width="200px"/>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 ">

    <div id="top">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="pull-center"><title> title </title></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#link1">link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#link2">link 2</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 </div>
     <div ng-view></div>   
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

for title you should use headings instead as `<title>` tag defines a title in the browser toolbar and should be placed in `<head></head>`

for layout that you described you can try the following code

```
 <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!-- for ratio 3:6 -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img ng-src="img/sky-logo.jpg" style="width:200px" />
        </div>
        <!-- for ratio 3:6 -->
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <!-- top half -->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="pull-center">title</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- bottom half -->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#link1">link 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#link2">link 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```